# How do I manually sort my folders in Solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio

I have some folders in my solution explorer tab. I want to sort them manually. Is that possible? Like, I have a folder named Admin, a folder named CSS, and a folder named User. I want to be able to sort it so that my CSS folder is on top, followed by my Admin and then user folder. Is their a way to do that?

Comment: I think it just puts them in alphabetical order, like windows file explorer would. AFAIK you can't specify an arbitrary order.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, I was afraid of that. Damnit! I hate that my admin folder is above my CSS and that my CSS folder isn't on top. Eh, what can you do. Poop! Thank you for answering!

Comment: "I hate that my admin folder is above my CSS and that my CSS folder isn't on top"...why?? Alphabetical order is pretty normal. It would get confusing if they were ordered randomly, you'd soon forget, if you didn't work on that project for a little while. And the CSS folder is only a few mm below it on the screen, it's not like it's hard to find!

Comment: @ADyson because if I don't use the folder consistently, I like to have what I am working on most in a compact area so I can switch to it. Plus, I'm OCD when it comes to order and how I want things.

Comment: My solution to that is simply to fold up the folders I'm not working on (so the list of files within them is not displayed). They're still visible, but as I said above, they only take up a few mm of space, so they're not in the way and I can easily see the folders I am more interested in.

Comment: Anyway I guess you'll have to find a way to overcome your OCD, or start writing a visual studio plugin which enables the functionality you want (assuming that's actually possible - I don't know the specifics of what the plugin architecture allows you to manipulate - it's just an idea for you to investigate.)

Answer (score 1):

Since "solution folder" names in the Visual Studio "Solution Explorer" tool window are arbitrary names stored in the `.sln` file (and not actual file system directory path names), you can change them without affecting the actual layout and functioning of things. So you can set the order you want by prefixing each solution folder name with sone consistent numbering scheme of your choice.

Note that the so-called "alphabetical" order the Solution Explorer uses for sorting is *case-insensitive*, and seems to ignore many punctuation characters when they occur at the start of node names. A useful exception is the exclamation point (`!`) character, which you can prefix at the start of whichever solution folders you want to put at the top. As noted above, numeric digits also work as expected.

[image]